# How do you make a different array for each discord server a bot is on in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord

I had been making a bot in discord where you could add items to a list and everyone could see them. It would going very smoothly, but I ran into a problem. When I tested to bot in multiple servers, the list stayed the same in each server, and I couldn't find out a way to fix it! I've tried looking up answers but the answers I found didn't have to do with my case, so I'm asking here. So, how am I able to create an array automatically for each server a discord bot is in? This could help others using arrays in their discord bot.

Comment: You will need to show us the code before we can help you...

Answer (score 0):

As a first approach, you can use the [HashMap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashmap) npm package.
HashMap permits to associate a key and a value.
So you are going to store for each server a list. And for the key, you are going to take the server ID.

Check the documentation for a list of all possibilities.

An example can be:

```js
var HashMap = require('hashmap');

var map = new HashMap();

//Store the item's list.
map.set("Your guild ID / message.guild.id", "Your item list");

//Then, in order to get it, just do.
map.get("Your guild ID / message.guild.id");
```

If you want more possibilities, you can always have a look at SQL/SQLite. For example, using [Enmap](https://enmap.evie.dev).